# How to make Windows10-like lock/login screen on ubuntu 20?

Tags: login-screen, lock-screen, 20.10

How to make Windows10-like lock/login screen on ubuntu 20?

I mean not only style, my point about randomize backgrounds from internet or local.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't simply use the Windows 10 greeter because it's not open source and elements in Windows are not modular like they are in Linux.  You'll need to work on (and ask about) each feature separately.

Comment: @Nmath I understand it. I am interested in the implementation of the very concept with random wallpaper from the Internet.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release, the closest by name is Ubuntu Core 20 (but no gui, no lock/login screen which has a wallpaper/background).  Ubuntu uses *yy* for *snap* only specialist releases, all server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format, eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Ubuntu releases with *yy* format are different products to the *yy.mm* major releases. For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I'd look for the theme via `sddm` though most are static (https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/101/order/latest/)

Comment: @guiverc I mean 20 series. 20.04 and 20.10. Facepalm, go away

Comment: Ubuntu has products, such as Ubuntu Core 20 that use the 20.  Canonical/Ubuntu have more products than just Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 20.10, and Ubuntu Core 20 is not completely compatible to the standard server & desktop releases (though all will run the same snaps).  Please be specific & don't make releases up (*IT is an industry where being specific matters*)